# Bug with my Android application

Tags: java, android, controls

It doesnt work if I add the prebuilt calender, digital clock and analog clock that comes with the androids development environment...

```
        <DigitalClock android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="DigitalClock"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/digitalClock1"></DigitalClock>

    <AnalogClock android:id="@+id/analogClock1" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"></AnalogClock>

    <CalendarView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/calendarView1" 
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/analogClock1"
     android:layout_below="@+id/digitalClock1"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></CalendarView>
```

Why..

ps.I tested without that chunk of code..the application runs perfectly

Comment: Can you give us the logcat error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look carefully at the [`CalendarView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html) documentation, you'll find this:

> Since: API Level 11

Which means it was introduced in Android 3.0 Honeycomb (which is not currently available for phones). Thus, if you were testing on a phone (or a pre-3.0 emulator), you'll get a `ClassNotFoundException` (I think), telling you it can't find `CalendarView`.

The reason why Eclipse is not telling you about this is probably that you have set the target SDK for your project to 11 or higher.

Comment: You need to set your target (using dropdown list) in your gui builder too. It is set to Android 3.0 as default.

Comment: yup it is the Calender view..i removed it and the application works..how do i fix the problem?

Comment: You don't use `CalendarView`, or you don't support Android versions below 3.0.